# Read Byte Array from a zip file in project folder in WP7

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-7, arrays

I have a zip file and I have to read its bytes and decrypt. How do I get the byte array from the file which I have added to the project and set its bulid action property as content. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bytes of the file this way:

```
    var res = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("yourFile", UriKind.Relative));

    var fileStream = res.Stream;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];

    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
```

Comment: When I use this I get MethodAccessException .

Comment: Hey it is still not working and giving the same exception. Is it that we have to only use isolated storage? If so how do I store it to Isolated Storage?

Comment: @Shilpa It's not necessary to use the isolated storage. Previous code was working ok for me. Anyway I have changed it, try the edited one, that uses `Application.GetResourceStream` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use This.

```
return File.ReadAllBytes( shapeFileZip.Name );
```

Its use For C# code.

Comment: I can't find ReadAllBytes Method in WP7 File class